# Using If statement with ember in a JS file

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am not sure how this works but i need to put an if statement in the following code. 
I know Javascript but not ember, still learning it as I go
My file is called: CatalogueListController.js
and the code with in:

```
App.CataloguelistController = Em.ArrayController.extend(Ember.PaginationSupport, {
needs: ["search", "accountBrowse"],
content: [],
total: 0,
isLoading: false,
outofcount: 0,
searchquery: '',
classid: 0,
attributelist: '',
processguid: '',
quotetypeMetaBinding: "App.metaDataController.QUOTETYPE",

addToBulk: function(context) {
        var self        = this,
    accountguid = App.selectedAccountGuid,
    quotetype   = (context && context.metacode) ? context.metacode : App.currentQuotetype,
    itemArray   = [];

       //some more code here    
},

//i need to put the if here if it is for a certain accountguid then have 
    currentViewList: true,
currentViewBulk: false,


    //else have this
currentViewList: false,
currentViewBulk: true,

mainPage: false,

andOr: [
    {"name": "Match All", "value": "AND"},
    {"name": "Match Any", "value": "OR"}
],
andOrSelected: 'AND',
```

i have put in comments where i need to have the if.
Any help please?
thanks

Comment: What is the event that will trigger the change? Can you show some jquery code, don't need to work, just to me know what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On init conditionally set those properties:

```
App.CataloguelistController = Em.ArrayController.extend(Ember.PaginationSupport, {
init: function(){
  this._super(); 
  if(//somecondition){
    this.set('currentViewList', true);
    this.set('currentViewBulk', false);
  }else{
  // set them to something else..
  }
}
```

Comment: This comment is for making two points clear and to inform other readers as well. In no case is this an attempt to affect the result. 1. init function is called once when the singleton controller is initially instanciated 2. make sure to call this._super(); within init function. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use computed properties. Also if you ever need to, you can bind computed properties with other properties that may change dynamically.(http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties/)

```
App.CataloguelistController = Em.ArrayController.extend(Ember.PaginationSupport, {
  needs: ["search", "accountBrowse"],
  .....

  currentViewList:function(){
    if(/*it is for a certain accountguid*/){
      return true;
    }else{
      return false;
    }
  }.property(),
  currentViewBulk:function(){
    if(/*it is for a certain accountguid*/){
      return true;
    }else{
      return false;
    }
  }.property(),

  .....
```